# How can i have my submit button forward to any email address entered?

Tags: html, email, web, html-email

I have a simple code.
I would like for the person to enter their email address In the box on the website and when submit is it, it sends to their email address that was entered.

Enter your e-mail below to find out when we launch!

```
<div id="subscribe">
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter your email address...">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    <div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: where is your attempt at the question?

Comment: You need some server side code to process your form (so start by picking a programming language), but you probably don't want to do that as it is likely to turn your form into a spam relay.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: google around for a php email form

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your html document:

```
<form action="sendemail.php" type="post">
<input type="text" name="emailBox" placeholder="enter your email address...">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then you're going to need to download WAMP or XAMP or some service that can process your PHP code because you will then need to make a PHP document named "sendemail.php" containing this code:

```
<?php
mail($_POST['emailBox'],"Email Subject Here", "Email Contents Here");
?>
```

More information on this topic can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Please note, that you shouldn't use this in a production site, as someone could use it as spam relay.